# Is the feat Whip Mastery applicable to scorpion whips?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, pathfinder-society

If I am proficient with both whips and scorpion whips; am I able to apply anything that benefits specifically whips, such as for instance the feat Whip Mastery, to a scorpion whip? Why or why not?

Please answer this question considering only PFS-legal material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, but it's complicated

The Ultimate Equipment Scorpion Whip says, in part:

> If you are proficient with both the scorpion whip and whip, you can use a scorpion whip in either the normal way (as a light performance weapon) or as a whip. When you use a scorpion whip as a whip, it is equivalent to a whip, but deals lethal damage and can harm creatures regardless of their armor bonus.

Thus, the whip from Ultimate Equipment *is* equivalent to a whip (when used a certain way) and that means you can use stuff that requires a whip with it. The one in Adventurer's Armory, however, is entirely its own weapon, the only connection with whips being if you gain proficiciency with a whip you have it in scorpion whips as well.  This mean's it's a whip sometimes (since it is, you know, a whip) but not when a mechanic is specifically talking about the individual weapon called 'whip'.  Whip Mastery's 'normal' line makes it clear it's talking about the whip weapon, not whip-like weapons in general.

Pathfinder Society *used* to allow the Ulitimate Equipment scorpion whip with pretty much no fuss at all, but that version [is now banned](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder/comments/2l7269/scorpion_whip_fixed_for_pfs_and_eventually/), and requires a rebuild.  *However*, while not an errata, the whip in Adventurer's Armory itself uses [different rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/clarifications) for PFS play, which alter it to function similarly to the whip in UE with respect to the quoted passage, though like the AA one otherwise:

> Adventurer's Armory
> Page 4—Change the last sentence of the scorpion whip's description to the following, "If you are proficient with both scorpion whips and whips, you can use a scorpion whip in either the normal way, as a typical light performance weapon, or as a whip. When you use a scorpion whip as a whip, it is otherwise equivalent to a whip, but it deals lethal damage and can harm creatures regardless of their armor bonus."

So, outside PFS **yes**, as long as you use Ultimate Equipment and not Adventurer's Armory, but inside PFS **yes**, but you must use Adventurer's Armory instead of Ultimate Equipment.

Within PFS, as long as you use your option to count as a whip and are using the legal scorpion whip, anything that requires or works with/on whips will be fulfilled by or work with/on your scorpion whip, respectively.

Comment: Would it make a difference for feats like Weapon Focus or the Warpriest's Focused Weapon feature?

Comment: @Nejosan as Ulimate Equipment or Adventurer's Armory, in or out of PFS, and while choosing to count as a whip or not? If the **yes** states the answer mentions are possible, anything that works on a whip or requires a whip will work on/with your scorpion whip unless it specifically calls out otherwise.

Comment: The Adventurer's Armory version in PFS, while choosing to count as a whip.

Comment: So if I took Weapon Focus: Whip, I would get +1 to attack with scorpion whips while using them as a whip, and I would be able to use scorpion whips as my Warpriest's Focused Weapon so long as I am using them as a whip?

Comment: @Nejosan That's what my answer says, yes. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can make that more clear?  I've edited it.

Comment: I think that the last edit covers it pretty well, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Based on [this forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder/comments/2l7269/scorpion_whip_fixed_for_pfs_and_eventually/) I would say yes, any feats that reference a Whip are also usable when wielding a Scorpion Whip, *if you're proficient in both.*

The wording references (emphasis added)

> If you are proficient with both the scorpion whip and whip, you can use a scorpion whip in either the normal way (as a light performance weapon) or **as a whip.**

Because of this line, (which Redditor neothelid points out is a difference in the PFS legal version from the non-legal version) you can use the Scorpion Whip as though it were a Whip. Any feats and abilities you have would apply as long as you use the Scorpion Whip as a One-Handed weapon (but not a Light weapon with Performance).